# Why does `doall` not force the sequence to be counted?

Tags: clojure, time-complexity

```
(counted? (map identity (range 100)))                  ;; false, expected 
(time (counted?  (doall  (map identity (range 100))))) ;; false, unexpected
(time (counted? (into '() (map identity (range 100))))) ;; true, expected - but slower
```

(Clojure `"1.8.0"`)

The first result is expected since `map` is lazy.

The second is unexpected for me, since after `doall` the entire sequence has been realized, is now in memory. Since the implementation probably has to walk through the list anyway, why not count it?

The third is a workaround. Is it idiomatic? Is there an alternative?

Comment: `counted?` asks for a property of a collection type: are you the kind of collection that can return its count in constant time? `doall` only realises a lazy seq but doesn’t change its type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you already know that lazy sequences are not `counted?`.

However, in your example, whilst `doall` realizes the entire sequence, it still returns *that* result as a `LazySeq`. Have a look at this REPL output:

```
user=> (class (doall (map identity (range 100))))
clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

Using something like `into` seems to be the right way to go to me; because you need to force your result into a non-lazy sequence. You say `into` is slower, but it still seems acceptably fast to me.

Nevertheless, you could perhaps improve the time performance by calling  `vec` on your result, instead of `into`:

```
user=> (time (counted? (into '() (map identity (range 100)))))
"Elapsed time: 0.287542 msecs"
true
user=> (time (counted? (vec (map identity (range 100)))))
"Elapsed time: 0.169342 msecs"
true
```

Note: I'm using Clojure 1.9, rather than 1.8 on my machine, so you may see different results.

### Update / corrections:

Commenters have respectfully pointed out that:

1) `time` is terrible for benchmarking, and doesn't really provide any useful evidence in this instance.

2) `(vec x)` substituted for `(list x)`; `(list x)` is a constant-time operation no matter what the contents of x.

3) `doall` returns its input as its output; you get a LazySeq if you passed in a LazySeq, or a map if you passed in a map, etc.

Comment: Using `(time (counted? (list (map identity) (range 100))))` is close for me to the list "benchmark"

Comment: This answer has a number of inaccuracies, most glaring of which being that as mentioned in the comments `(list x)` is a constant-time operation no matter what the contents of `x` (and likewise for `vector`). Also, you write that `doall` returns its result wrapped in a LazySeq, which is only sometimes correct. Rather, `doall` returns its input as its output; you get a LazySeq if you passed in a LazySeq, or a map if you passed in a map, etc. Finally, `time` is terrible for benchmarking, and doesn't really provide any convincing evidence at all.